# Assign column names to select columns of dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I've imported a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) in which the columns from #5 onwards are dates that need to be cleaned as they have the form `X1.10.20` and I would like to have the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.  I am using `gsub()` to clean the data into a recognizable form for [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) and then converting with `mdy()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- gsub("X", "", names(df))           #remove leading X
names(df) <- gsub("\\.", "-", names(df))        #convert . to -
```

The dated columns now have the format: `M-D-YY`

```
dates <- mdy(names(df[,-c(1:4)])) #take current names and assign converted names to `dates` vector
```

The dates vector now contains dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. I would like to take this `dates` vector and assign it as the names from columns `4:length(df)`

I have tried the following:

`names(df[,-c(1:4)]) <- dates` , however the column names in the original data frame remain unchanged. and have the format `M-D-YY` still.

I feel I may be overthinking this and there is likely an easier method to rename specific columns. I have tried `rename()` as well from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) but have only had success with naming columns individually, and this dataset has hundreds of columns.

How can I go about this? Appreciate your input...

Comment: You probably need some prefixes, since column names in R beginning with a number are not valid. You also may want to look into `?make.names`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `names` argument should be

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- as.character(mdy(names(df)[-c(1:4)]))
names(df)[-c(1:4)] <- dates
```

---

This can be avoided if we use `check.names = FALSE`

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work if I also converted the `dates` vector to character strings with `dates <- as.character(dates)`. Otherwise I was getting converted values reading `18284`, `18289`, `18294` etc.  I'm guessing I cannot set column names as Date types, is this correct?

Comment: @KVSEA the reason is that `Date` class is stored iinternally as numeric.  It gets coereced to that type.  By converting to `character`, it remains